# Pretty URL via Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I'm building a dynamically populated profile page for my site users. This currently uses the following URL structure:

```
https://example.com/members-list-profile/?&uid=XX
```

I'd like to improve the look of the URL by inserting the user's *nicename* to create this URL structure:

```
https://example.com/members-list-profile/{nicename}/?uid=XX
```

I know I should be able to do this using a fairly simply rewrite rule in `.htaccess`, but haven't been able to get the right rule setup.

How can I get this structure / rewrite setup?

Comment: What have you tried? Presumably you have already changed the URLs in WordPress (in your internal links) and you need to "remove" (not "insert") the `{nicename}` part of the URL?

Comment: Any reasoning for the downvote, downvoter? You're entitled to your opinion but it helps no-one if you don't clarify the perceived problem.

Comment: @MrWhite The building the link is not an issue. It's the redirect in htaccess that will route the "pretty" url into the real querystring based url that is the issue.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted. (I agree, downvotes without comments are not particularly helpful.) I guess the downvote might be because you've not shown what you have tried? But anyway...

Comment: @MrWhite I didn't think it was you, sorry if it came across as if I did. As for the reasoning, it doesn't matter. Donwvoted without a comment helps no-one. I may have a low score on this exchange but I know my way around SO. Downvoting without any comment is just a bit arrogant IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

> It's the redirect in htaccess that will route the "pretty" url into the real querystring based url that is the issue.

So, it would seem you need to "remove" the `/{nicename}` portion from the "pretty" URL of the form `https://example.com/members-list-profile/{nicename}/?uid=XX`.

Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file (*before* the WordPress front-controller) using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^(members-list-profile/)[^/]+/$ $1 [L]
```

However, unless this maps to a physical file (in which case you should rewrite directly to that file, rather than let mod_dir issue a subrequest) then this might not work with WordPress, since WP still routes the URL based on physical/visible URL - it doesn't necessarily see the rewritten URL. You could issue an external redirect to get around this, but that really defeats the point of having `{nicename}` in the URL to begin with.

Something like this should probably be done entirely within WordPress, not `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. I'm aware that it should be doable within WordPress. It's just that .htaccess is marginally quicker and less demanding on the server since it's not having to spin-up WordPress and access the DB.